# How to convert dynamically table data into XML format in java and show it in browser with XML format

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

In java, I am getting data from SAP table via RFC in table. This table has approx 6000 rows. I want to convert it into XML format and shows into browser.

I am writing a method which will fetch data from SAP database via RFC and I have converted this method into web service. When I call this web service it gets the data and shows in console of my eclipse  IDE. But I want to write it as when anyone call my web service it shows data in browser in XML format.

Can any one help me please.

Comment: Well then you haven't really converted it into a web service, have you? A web service does not output to the console (unless it's a CGI script, but Java does not use CGI). I think you need to read some documentation.

Comment: I have first write a Hello method in eclipse using java and converted it into web service by using Axis2.My method simply returns hello!!name.When I right click on WebApp it gives URL of WSDL then I click on services.URL: http://172.19.3.112:8080/WebApp/Hello?wsdl.I have exported WAR file of this WebApp and deployed into tomcat 7.0.42. URL of my web service is http://172.19.3.112:8080/WebApp/Hello/sayHello?name='Ravi'.When I access this URL from another machine I get 'Hello !!! Ravi' in XML format in browser as a response.This is my complete process in making web services.Am I wrong?

Comment: If I am right then I want in the same way to write a method which connects with SAP and fetches the emplyee details and show it in the browser through URL.For this purpose, I have written a method which connects with SAP and fetches the data and collects in table format.I want to show all this table data in browser when any body access URL of this web service in browser like Hello web service.

Comment: Hello http://stackoverflow.com/users/495796/robin-green . I have studied documentation. Can you help me please.

Comment: Actually, I know how to make web services in java with Eclipse IDE using axis 2. I have made it but in my current scenario I have to show dynamic data into xml format.I am using JAXB architecture for xml.

Comment: sorry, I do not help with anything related to SAP